# Java: split text file into multiple List

Tags: java

I'm looking for an efficient way to split a text file into a set of ArrayList. The text file is a Thread dump and I'd like to create a List for every single Thread. Every thread is separated by an empty line.
For example, taken the following file:

```
"management-handler-thread - 66" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe960111000 nid=0x4cea waiting on condition [0x00007fe96c25c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006019cbbd0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)

"management-handler-thread - 65" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe968185800 nid=0x4ce9 waiting on condition [0x00007fe96c35d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006019cbbd0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
```

The first List should contain:

```
"management-handler-thread - 66" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe960111000 nid=0x4cea waiting on condition [0x00007fe96c25c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
. . .
```

And the second List should contain:

```
"management-handler-thread - 65" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe968185800 nid=0x4ce9 waiting on condition [0x00007fe96c35d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
. . . .
```

What would you recommend to do that ? (Iteration, Regular expression ..)
Thanks

Comment: Iterate over lines, insert depending on read data to proper list

Comment: How big is your input file? You most likely don't want to load a big log file into memory at once but use streams.

Comment: Why do you want to write the result into ArrayLists? You could also write them into separate files directly. Use a BufferedReader for the input and PrintWriters for the output files and each time you encounter an empty line you write the current entry into the appropriate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for regular expressions, just read the file line by line...

```
List<List<String>> dumpedThreads = new ArrayList<>();
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("path/to/thread-dump.txt")) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        List<String> thisThread = null;
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
                thisThread = null;
            } else {
                if (thisThread == null) {
                    thisThread = new ArrayList<>();
                    dumpedThreads.add(thisThread);
                }
                thisThread.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only work if `thread-dump.txt` is sorted by thread.